# Image control not updating after button click event or calling a different function

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, kinect

I have an Image control in the WPF application which needs to be updated from a different function once a click event fires. The background worker runs the function which contains a switch logic to decide which function to call based on the state of the program.

**The issue is that once the button click event is fired and a different function (Pulse) is called, the Image control (OpenCVFeed)  doesn't update anymore** and is stuck. I'm not sure if thats due to some thread access issues. The function Pulse is being called successfully, but the image control isn't being updated.

```
this.Loaded += delegate
     {
        appMode = Modes.Detection;
        //region KinectVariableInitialization..
        //endregion KinectVariablesInitialization
         OpenCVFeed.DataContext = colorManager;

         BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
         // bw.DoWork += (a, b) => Pulse();
         bw.DoWork += (a, b) => RunApplication();
         bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (c, d) => bw.RunWorkerAsync();
         bw.RunWorkerAsync();
     };

    private void RunApplication()
    {
      switch (appMode)
      {
        case Modes.Detection:
           Detection();
           break;
        case Modes.Game:
           Pulse();
           break;
        case Modes.Analysis:
           break;
      }
    }

    private void Detection()
    {
      using (ColorImageFrame imageFrame = _sensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(200))
      using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = _sensor.DepthStream.OpenNextFrame(200))
       {
         if(imageFrame == null)
            return;

          Image<Rgb, Byte> imageCapture = new Image<Rgb, byte>(640, 480);
          using (imageCapture = imageFrame.ToOpenCVImage<Rgb, byte>())
          {
            Image<Gray, Byte> grayImg = imageCapture.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            if (squareMat.findChessboardCorners(ref grayImg, out squareMat.cornersDetected))
            {
              this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => OpenCVFeed.Source = grayImg.ToBitmapSource()));
              if(captureClicked)
              {
                 squareMat.StoreCorners(squareMat.cornersDetected);
                 this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(this, "Matrix Captured Successfully!")));
                 appMode = Modes.Game;
              }
             }
              else
              {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => colorManager.Update(imageFrame)));
             } 
           } 
         } 
      }

      private void captureButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        captureClicked = true;
      }

      private void Pulse()
      {
        using (ColorImageFrame imageFrame = _sensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(200))
        {
          if (imageFrame == null || depthFrame == null)
                return;
       //Some Kinect Logic..
          this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => colorManager.Update(imageFrame)));
         }
       }
```

The colorManager is a different Class (ColorManager.cs) object holding the Update function responsible for updating the Image Control (OpenCVFeed)  via Binding to Bitmap path:

```
    public WriteableBitmap Bitmap { get; private set; }
    public void Update(ReplayColorImageFrame frame)
    {
        var pixelData = new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];
        frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
        if (Bitmap == null)
        {
          Bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frame.Width, frame.Height,
                                         96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
        }
        int stride = Bitmap.PixelWidth * Bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
        Int32Rect dirtyRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, Bitmap.PixelWidth, Bitmap.PixelHeight);
        Bitmap.WritePixels(dirtyRect, pixelData, stride, 0);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: The problem may be that you reuse the WriteableBitmap instance assigned to the Bitmap property. Although you fire the PropertyChanged event, a Binding to the Bitmap property ignores the event, because the object in the Bitmap property hasn't changed. But, WritePixels should have changed the existing bitmap, so I'm not sure about all this. Try how it behaves if you create a new WriteableBitmap each time.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I changed my colorManager.Update method to return a WriteableBitmap and then manually set the OpenCVFeed.Source = colorManager.Update(imageFrame) and it works!. So the RaisePropertyChange event isnt working?? What could be the possible reason?. Your haunch is right about this, but I cant figure out why the binding isnt updating.

Comment: As said, the Binding detects that the source object hasn't changed. It is the same object as before. So it simply ignores the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: The bitmap is updating though, since Kinect is firing new color image frames every 200 milliseconds.